# How to optimize this query generated from a View?

Tags: views, database

In a D6 site, I log queries and get this monster frequently in the [MySQL slow query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/slow-query-log.html):

> Query_time: 13.817393  Lock_time: 0.000261  Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 3655810 SET timestamp=1366964215;

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT(node.nid) AS nid, 
               node.title AS node_title,
               node.language AS node_language,
               votingapi_vote_node.value AS votingapi_vote_node_value,
               node_counter.totalcount AS node_counter_totalcount,
               term_data.name AS term_data_name,
               term_data.vid AS term_data_vid,
               term_data.tid AS term_data_tid,
               comments.timestamp AS comments_timestamp
          FROM node node
    INNER JOIN votingapi_vote votingapi_vote_node ON node.nid = votingapi_vote_node.content_id AND votingapi_vote_node.content_type = 'node'
     LEFT JOIN node_counter node_counter ON node.nid = node_counter.nid
     LEFT JOIN term_node term_node ON node.vid = term_node.vid
     LEFT JOIN term_data term_data ON term_node.tid = term_data.tid
     LEFT JOIN comments comments ON node.nid = comments.nid
    INNER JOIN node_access na ON na.nid = node.nid
         WHERE (na.grant_view >= 1 AND ((na.gid = 0 AND na.realm = 'all') OR (na.gid = 0 AND na.realm = 'og_pub lic')))
           AND (node.type in ('photo'))
      GROUP BY nid
      ORDER BY comments_timestamp DESC) count_alias;
```

This isn't custom query; it is coming from one of my Views.

I am wondering how can I optimize it? What index(es) should I generate?

Comment: Optimising SQL isn't really on-topic for this site. What does your query do?

Comment: I'm guessing it's a COUNT query generated by Views in order to display a pager. Is that right? Because if so there may be a Drupal-related answer.

Comment: Is this your own query, or one that came from Views?

Comment: I've seen pager queries like this in views - switching to http://drupal.org/project/views_litepager should fix it

Comment: Guys, as you guessed this is a views generated query that sorts photo nodes based on their votes.

Comment: +1 for Views Lite Pager. It removes the requirement to count all possible entries before displaying a pager.